# How to make the size of ImageView independent to parent when it is larger than the parent?

Tags: android, xml

for example, if a 80dp square layout contains a smaller ImageView, the size of ImageView will not be scaled:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="80dp"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:background="#FFFF00"
android:clipChildren="true">
<ImageView
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

but if the parent is smaller than the ImageView, eg:30dp:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="30dp"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:background="#FFFF00"
android:clipChildren="true">
<ImageView
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

it would be scaled automatically:

[image]

but I want the ImageView cropped instead of scaled:

[image]

how can I get this crop effect in xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is alot of techniques available.
Try to Add both attribute in your ImageView xml

```
android:scaleType="matrix"
```

OR

```
Use margin-right,left,up,down.
```

OR

```
Search Icon size in google and then edit this icon in photoshop give it a fix size of icon .
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding following attribute in your ImageView xml

```
android:scaleType="matrix"
```

hope it helps :)